# How add \ in front of this $ in my string?

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $cmd = 'this is a "testin$g" ok';
print Dumper($cmd);
```

$VAR1 = 'this is a "testin$g" ok';

```
my $cmd = 'this is a "testin$g" ok';
$cmd =~ s/\$/\\\$/;
print Dumper($cmd);
```

$VAR1 = 'this is a "testin\\$g" ok';

I am trying to end up with a string that looks like this: 'this is a "testin\$g" ok'.
A single \ in front of the $. But even though I replace the $ with \$ it ends up with two instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex and string are both correct.
Data::Dumper escapes the characters itself.

For printing a simple string just use

```
print $cmd."\n";
```

And you'll see it's ok.

Also, try this to see how Dumper escapes the characters

```
print Dumper('this is a "testin\$g" ok');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution is correct. If you executed the following, you'd see that `$cmd` contains but a single backslash.

```
print("$cmd\n");    # this is a "testin\$g" ok
```

Data::Dumper prints a string literal that, when executed, would create the string in the structure.

```
$VAR1 = 'this is a "testin\\$g" ok';
```

indicates the variable dumped contains

```
this is a "testin\$g" ok
```

because

```
this is a "testin\$g" ok
```

gets assigned to `$VAR1` when you execute

```
$VAR1 = 'this is a "testin\\$g" ok';
```